# Read DateTime value in correct format with JQuery (passed from controller to ajax)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime

`/Date(1482048633480)/` is the result when `appending()` the `DateTime` value into HTML.

```
$("#Date").append($('<div> '+ data.DateTimeFromController+' </div>'))
```

How to read `data.DateTimeFromController` in `MM/DD/YYYY Hour/Min/Sec AM/PM` format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/206384/447156 ?

Comment: @SonerGönül Almost, but I couldn't find in MM/DD/YYYY Hour/Min/sec AM/PM format.

Comment: You can always format the `DataTime` to a stringi n the controller ( and pass that formatted string ) :)

Comment: check out this `var meridiem;
var hr;
var jsonDate = '1297246301973';
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var hrs = currentTime.getHours();
if( hrs > 12){
 hr = hrs - 12;
meridiem = 'PM';
}
else{
hr = hrs;
meridiem = 'AM';
}

var min = currentTime.getMinutes();
var sec = currentTime.getSeconds();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year +"  " + hr+"/" + min +"/" +sec +" "+meridiem;
alert(date);`